Fatal error ‘llvm-c/Types.h’ file not found
I use the llvm doc to install llvm-18 : LLVM Debian/Ubuntu packages
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 18 all

And then I successfull install llvm-18.
> clang++-18 --version locate clang++-18
Ubuntu clang version 18.1.6 (++20240513065742+09615ce869b0-1~exp1~20240513065903.119)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

However, when I use #include <llvm-18/llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h> the clangd tell me 'llvm-c/Types.h' file not found How can I deal with it?

Libraries often expect that header search paths are set to point to their "root", which I suppose you haven't done. Hence your explicit llvm-18 in your path -- I suspect that the library itself doesn't want that to be there.

I use #include "llvm/IR/LLVMConext.h"  , but the cland cannot find the path @ChristianStieber

Thanks, I have dealt with this problem, my CMakeLists.txt have problem, I should use find_package to find llvm
